# VBA Excel: change offset based on active sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out how i can make a offset based on the Active sheet number.

Example:

Right now in sheet number 2 in Cell "B1" I have a number set of 17000
On the same sheet at B8:B I have a column of numbers going down with certain values that I would like to add up to my base of 17000. Once I make a new sheet I want "A1" To have that value of the other 2 numbers added up.

I have a Code that "Fills in" The active sheet that I'm using.

But how could I make it that in each new sheet it will go 1 position down in column B8:B

So sheet 2 has the values that will be used.

- New sheet nmbr 5 gets created which will need sheet 2 "B1" + "B8"
- New sheet nmbr 6 gets created which will need sheet 2 "B1" + "B9"
- New sheet nmbr 7 gets created which will need sheet 2 "B1" + "B10"

And so on and so on.

```
Sub KnopKlik()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS1 As Worksheet
Dim WS2 As Worksheet
Dim WS3 As Worksheet
Dim Active As Worksheet
Dim Titel1
Dim Titel2

 Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
 Set WS1 = WB.Sheets(1)
 Set WS2 = WB.Sheets(2)
 Set WS3 = WB.Sheets(3)
 Set Active = WB.ActiveSheet
 Set MC = Active.Range("B9")

 Titel1 = WS2.Range("B1") 'Base number of 17000
 Titel2 = WS2.Range("B8") 'Has to be added up to 17000 depending on sheet number
 column1 = Sheets(3).Cells(1, 3).Value

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

'============================================================
Sheets(1).Visible = True ' Activate Sheets
Sheets(2).Visible = True
Sheets(3).Visible = True

Active.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = "Unit " & (Titel1 + Titel2)

'This is the line that is suppose to write the question i asked.

'=============================================================================
' Between these lines is a bunch of code i left out cause its irrelivant to the question.
'=============================================================================


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Active.Select

Sheets(1).Visible = xlVeryHidden
Sheets(3).Visible = xlVeryHidden
Sheets(4).Visible = xlVeryHidden

MsgBox ("Done")

End Sub
```

I hope the question isn't to hard to understand. I got what i want exactly in my head but i find it hard to explain in English :P

Comment: So the line Titel2 = WS2.Range("B8")  should be B9 on sheet 5 and b10 in sheet6?

Comment: No TItel2 Should be Sheet 2 B8 when used on sheet 5. And should be Sheet 2 B9  when used on sheet 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try

```
 Titel2 = WS2.cells(4 + activesheet.index,2)
```

Comment: Wow.... I have been overthinking it so much, That i was unaware of using "Activesheet.index"